# Make it so when I click on a element, it directs me to another element on the same page and indicates that it's visited

Tags: html, css

In this case my code is:

```html
<button><a href="#A">Click Me</a></button>
```

(I did not know how to make it so the entire element was clickable so i used a button instead, please advise)

CSS:

```css
.sidebarhome:visited{
    border: 1px;
}
```

I have some code for the indicator which i wish to use which is a glowing effect:

```css
box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 0px rgba(255,165,0,1);
transition: .8s ease;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nesting two clickable elements. Avoid this. Just use a link instead (`<a href="#A">` in your case).

The `:visited` pseudo class is not used in this manner. What you are looking for is `:target`, which will be applied on the element with the ID you are referencing.

```
<a href="#my-section">Go to my section</a>

<!-- other stuff -->

<div id="my-section">
  <p>Welcome to my section!</p>
</div>
```

…and in your stylesheet:

```
#my-section:target {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but  is there a way for me to have a scroll animation to the target? Or will that be too complicated.

Comment: Yes, it's completely doable using either JavaScript or pure CSS with `scroll-behavior: smooth;`. The latter is [not fully supported across browsers yet](https://caniuse.com/css-scroll-behavior). [This Codepen](https://codepen.io/frippz/pen/ExZGvpa?editors=1100) does both target styling and smooth scrolling via CSS in supporting browsers.

Comment: How do i make it so when i click on another target link the current indicator disappears?

Comment: That will happen automatically, since `:target` works only for the currently targeted element. Click on another fragment link, leading to another element, will also move the highlight. 

Please remember to mark my answer as accepted if you feel that it answered your original question.

Comment: @Æłéséł1802 Regardless if you continue the discussion or not, your original question has been answered, so you should mark this as the accepted answer.